# Why using Tasks.Wait() rollback events and using a cancelation token doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, cancellation

So what I don't understand is what happens in the following application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TaskVersion:");
        Task t = new Task(waitCB, "something");
        t.Wait(1000);

        Console.WriteLine("TaskWithCancelationTokenVersion:");
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task tct = new Task(waitCB, "something", cts.Token);
        tct.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        cts.Cancel();

        Console.WriteLine("ThreadVersion:");
        Thread th = new Thread(waitCB);
        th.Start("something");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        th.Abort();
    }

    static void waitCB(object ob)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object is " + ob);
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

At the first example I think that the program should execute the line: `Console.WriteLine("Object is " + ob);` and then when it will abort `t.Wait(1000)` there isn't any line.

The programs' output is:

```
TaskVersion:
TaskWithCancelationTokenVersion:
Object is something
ThreadVersion:
Object is something
```

So `task.Wait()` it's just a way to abruptly close a thread and it rollback what it has done?

Comment: Basically task.Wait(timeout) doesn't care if task was finished or not after timeout expires. You should use cancellation token to check its IsCancellationRequested property & call ThrowIfCancellationRequested to cancel the task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issues have nothing to do with cancellation or `Wait()`, you just forgot to `Start()` the first `Task`.

Comment: I was just about to post that same answer.